# CodeIgniter partially override a method

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am trying to refactor this code a bit. Originally I had two different models, both extending MY_Model. However, most of the code was repetitive so now I am having First_model extend MY_Model and Second_model extends First_model. I cleaned up most of code from Second_model that it inherits from First_model, but I have several methods within Second_model that are only slightly different from the same method in First_model. Consider the following code:

**First_model**

```
class First_model extends MY_Model
{

private function getPostsByPostIDs($postIDs)
    {
        $postIDs = $this->strictCastIntArray($postIDs);
        $postIDSqlArray = implode(",", $postIDs);
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('n');
        $sql = "SELECT
                    post.id,
                    post.useraccount_id,
                    user.first_name user_first_name,
                    user.last_name user_last_name,
                    user.gender user_gender,
                    user.profile_pic user_profile_pic,
                    post.class_id,
                    post.school_id school_id,
                    school.display_name school_name,
                    school.state,
                    school.city,
                    post.karma_awarded_id,
                    post.is_parent_post,
                    post.reply_to_post_id,
                    post.comment_text,
                    post.image_url,
                    post.ts_created,
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post.ts_created) post_timestamp,
                    post.ts_modified,
                    user.facebook_uid user_facebook_id,
                    user.id user_id,
                    sum(ka.karma) monthly_karma
                 FROM
                    WallPosts post
                    JOIN UserAccounts account ON (account.id = post.useraccount_id)
                    JOIN Users user ON (user.id = account.user_id)
                    LEFT JOIN Schools school ON (post.school_id = school.id)
                    LEFT JOIN KarmaAwarded ka ON (ka.user_id IN (SELECT 
                                                                    IFNULL(u_all.id, user.id)
                                                                 FROM UserAccounts ua
                                                                    INNER join Users u ON u.id = ua.user_id
                                                                    LEFT join Users u_all ON u_all.facebook_uid = u.facebook_uid
                                                                 WHERE ua.id = post.useraccount_id)  
                                                  AND YEAR(ka.ts_created) = {$year} 
                                                  AND MONTH(ka.ts_created) = {$month})
                 WHERE
                    post.id IN ({$postIDSqlArray})
                    GROUP BY post.id";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $queryResults = $query->result_array();
        $functionResults = array();
        foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
            $functionResults[$row["id"]] = $row;
        }
        return $functionResults;
    }
}
```

**Second_model**

```
class Second_model extends First_model
{

private function getPostsByPostIDs($postIDs)
    {
        $postIDs = $this->strictCastIntArray($postIDs);
        $postIDSqlArray = implode(",", $postIDs);
        $year = date("Y");
        $month = date("n");
        $sql = "SELECT
                    post.id,
                    post.useraccount_id,
                    user.first_name user_first_name,
                    user.last_name user_last_name,
                    user.gender user_gender,
                    user.profile_pic user_profile_pic,
                    post.class_id,
                    post.school_id school_id,
                    school.display_name school_name,
                    school.state,
                    school.city,
                    post.karma_awarded_id,
                    post.is_parent_post,
                    post.reply_to_post_id,
                    post.comment_text,
                    post.image_url,
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post.ts_created) ts_created,
                    post.ts_modified,
                    user.facebook_uid user_facebook_id,
                    user.id user_id,
                    SUM(ka.karma) monthly_karma,
                    post.answer_status_flags
                FROM
                    WallPosts post
                    JOIN UserAccounts account ON (account.id = post.useraccount_id)
                    JOIN Users user ON (user.id = account.user_id)
                    LEFT JOIN Schools school ON (post.school_id = school.id)
                    LEFT JOIN KarmaAwarded ka ON (ka.user_id IN (
                        SELECT
                            IFNULL(u_all.id, user.id)
                        FROM
                            UserAccounts ua
                            INNER JOIN Users u ON (u.id = ua.user_id)
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u_all ON (u_all.facebook_uid = u.facebook_uid)
                        WHERE ua.id = post.useraccount_id)
                        AND YEAR(ka.ts_created) = {$year} AND MONTH(ka.ts_created) = {$month})
                WHERE
                    post.id IN ({$postIDSqlArray})
                GROUP BY post.id";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $queryResults = $query->result_array();
        $functionResults = array();
        foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
            $functionResults[$row['id']] = $row;
        }
        return $functionResults;
    }
}
```

Notice the only thing different is the query in the $sql variable. I am wondering can I somehow make the method in the first model protected and only change the query in the second? Or is there a more efficient way to trim down this code? I have several methods this same thing applies to and it seems a bit much to keep redefining the methods in the new Class.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about pass the $sql as a variable in your models:

In your First Model you would have:

```
private $sqlPostId = '';

public function __construct() {
    $this->sqlPostId = "SELECT
                    post.id,
                    post.useraccount_id,
                    user.first_name user_first_name,
                    user.last_name user_last_name,
                    user.gender user_gender,
                    user.profile_pic user_profile_pic,
                    post.class_id,
                    post.school_id school_id,
                    school.display_name school_name,
                    school.state,
                    school.city,
                    post.karma_awarded_id,
                    post.is_parent_post,
                    post.reply_to_post_id,
                    post.comment_text,
                    post.image_url,
                    post.ts_created,
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post.ts_created) post_timestamp,
                    post.ts_modified,
                    user.facebook_uid user_facebook_id,
                    user.id user_id,
                    sum(ka.karma) monthly_karma
                 FROM
                    WallPosts post
                    JOIN UserAccounts account ON (account.id = post.useraccount_id)
                    JOIN Users user ON (user.id = account.user_id)
                    LEFT JOIN Schools school ON (post.school_id = school.id)
                    LEFT JOIN KarmaAwarded ka ON (ka.user_id IN (SELECT 
                                                                    IFNULL(u_all.id, user.id)
                                                                 FROM UserAccounts ua
                                                                    INNER join Users u ON u.id = ua.user_id
                                                                    LEFT join Users u_all ON u_all.facebook_uid = u.facebook_uid
                                                                 WHERE ua.id = post.useraccount_id)  
                                                  AND YEAR(ka.ts_created) = {$year} 
                                                  AND MONTH(ka.ts_created) = {$month})
                 WHERE
                    post.id IN ({$postIDSqlArray})
                    GROUP BY post.id";

}

private function getPostsByPostIDs($postIDs)
{
        $postIDs = $this->strictCastIntArray($postIDs);
        $postIDSqlArray = implode(",", $postIDs);
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('n');

        // Here you use the defined variable in the constructor
        $query = $this->db->query($this->sqlPostId);

        $queryResults = $query->result_array();
        $functionResults = array();
        foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
            $functionResults[$row["id"]] = $row;
        }
        return $functionResults;
    }
```

And then you just have to change the SQL in the construct function in your second Model and go.